# FFmpeg failed to transcode - Error while opening encoder for output stream

Tags: php, ffmpeg

**Reported errors**

PHPVideoToolkit error: Execute error. It was not possible to encode "/home/onevid/public_html/sites/default/files/videos/original/qw_1.mpg" as FFmpeg returned an error. The error is with the video codec of the input file. FFmpeg reports the error to be "Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height".

**Executed commands and output**

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i '/home/onevid/public_html/sites/default/files/videos/original/qw_1.mpg' -vf 'scale=540:360' -strict experimental -vcodec 'h263' -qscale '12' -acodec 'aac' -ac '2' -pass '1' -passlogfile '/tmp/1377530626-521b73028a987-multipass'  -y /tmp/1377530626-521b73028a7ea.mp4
ffmpeg version 1.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug 26 2013 15:10:42 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
  configuration: --disable-yasm
  libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
  libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
[mpeg @ 0x2e89160] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5015467 microseconds
Input #0, mpeg, from '/home/onevid/public_html/sites/default/files/videos/original/qw_1.mpg':
  Duration: 00:00:14.00, start: 0.011978, bitrate: 3235 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 160 kb/s
Please use -q:a or -q:v, -qscale is ambiguous
[h263 @ 0x2e8b180] The specified picture size of 540x360 is not valid for the H.263 codec.
Valid sizes are 128x96, 176x144, 352x288, 704x576, and 1408x1152. Try H.263+.
Output #0, mp4, to '/tmp/1377530626-521b73028a7ea.mp4':
    Stream #0:0: Video: h263, yuv420p, 540x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], q=2-31, pass 1, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: none, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg2video -> h263)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (mp2 -> aac)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Comment: "The specified picture size of 540x360 is not valid for the H.263 codec." seems a hint...

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find solution? where is the problem?

Comment: Video encoding is so awesome. I got a "height not divisible by 2". Super advanced video encoding and THAT is a problem!?